# Named Entity Recognition - how to handle overlapping entities in the dataset?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to perform named entity recognition with an RNN as a simple baseline model.

I have a dataset containing many sentences and information about where they have entities (start position of entity in sentence, end position """, entity label). While reading it in, I noticed some overlaps of these entity annotations. I will make this clear with an example sentence:

```
"I am on a holiday, staying at   a hotel from 12.08 until 13.08 in London."

O  O  O  O    O       O     Loc Loc Loc  Loc   Loc   Loc  Loc   Loc  Loc

O  O  O  O    O       O     O    O   O   Time  Time  Time Time  O     O
```

You see, there is a significant overlap between the 'Loc' (Location) and 'Time' label. I have multiple ideas how I could handle it, but since I am not that experienced in NER, I have difficulties to settle for one. Here are my ideas and what I think about them so far:

1. Add the example sentence twice to the dataset, one version for each label, like this:

```
"I am on a holiday, staying at   a hotel from 12.08 until 13.08 in London."

O  O  O  O    O       O     Loc Loc Loc  Loc   Loc   Loc  Loc   Loc  Loc

I am on a holiday, staying at   a hotel from 12.08 until 13.08 in London.

O  O  O  O    O       O     O    O   O   Time  Time  Time Time  O     O
```

This, however, results in the final model not learning that there could be 2 entities overlapping with each other, which particularly in the given example would make sense to predict. But I could look at how high the probability the second highest predicted label for a given word is and if its above a certain threshold, decide to include both labels in the prediction results. I fear it would be finnicky to find that threshold though.

2. Giving tuples as labels at the overlapping positions:

```
"I am on a holiday, staying at   a hotel from      12.08 until 13.08 in London."

O  O  O  O    O       O     Loc Loc Loc  (Loc,Time) (L,T)(L,T)  (L,T) Loc  Loc
```

I have many different labels in the dataset, so this surely will result in few learning examples for each kind of tuple. I am worried about robustness here.

3. Cut these kind of sentences from my dataset (they make about 20%, but it would still be enough left for training). Cheap and dirty. I honestly want to avoid this one and rather find a solution.

I have no coding issues here. Its all about how to best handle these overlapping entities and I would be really gratefull for any tips and insights on the matter.